# Use Bip 39 mnemonic words to restore Samourai wallet to another wallet

Tags: mnemonic-seed, samourai-wallet, bluewallet

I want to access my Samourai wallet from a different type of wallet: either Blue- or Sparrow Wallet by using the 12 word mnemonic and passphrase.

Is this recommended? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the Samourai mnuemonic, and wallet password, entered it into Sparrow Wallet. I could use the main Samourai wallet and addresses fully.

The Whirlpool section wasn't available.

No special config in Sparrow needed to import.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work so long as both wallets implement BIP-39, BIP-32 etc and so long as both wallets use the same derivation path.

Comment: Thanks! I tried in this Sparrow and it worked!